# Java applet for Tower of Hanoi

Tags: java, javascript, towers-of-hanoi

I am planning to write a Java applet for Tower of Hanoi similar to link(
http://www.mazeworks.com/hanoi/index.htm )
Can you suggest how should I start and proceed.

And, btw, does it require multi threading?

And also, major part of my doubt is

- to make a disc being clickable and being able to drag and drop the disc on a tower.
- detect a tower (if a disc is being dragged using mouse)

Comment: Hmm, would this be a homework problem?

Comment: Java is to Javascript, what Car is to Carpet... I'm just saying.

Comment: @Cristian: Many applets take their input via Javascript.  When you're talking Java *applets*, there is a reason to connect the two.

Comment: Some applets do so... but not all of them. So... no reason to mix those two complete different terms.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this http://www.rstack.com/hanoi/hanoi_src.html or http://stud1.tuwien.ac.at/~e9125168/javaa/jtower.html. As far as threading see my comment on Jonathan M Davis's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javafx it is easier than core java. [Here](http://javafx.com/samples/TOH/index.html) is an example